# Analytics not tracked for Firebase Dynamic link created with custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a Firebase dynamic link with custom domain from the Firebase Console then the Firebase dynamic links analytics is not tracking the clicks even after waiting for 3-4 days.

If I create a Firebase dynamic link without custom domain then the analytics is tracking properly.

It seems this issue is specific for dynamic links created with a custom domain.

Could anyone help me with tracking analytics for Firebase dynamic links with custom domain?